# Logcat Null Check Returning False Positive

Tags: java, android, logcat

I'm doing a simple test (attempting to null check a value) and just for kicks I decided to null check a make believe / nonexistant value: "striiing" which does not exist anywhere in my source code. I then checked my logcat and realized this non existent value appears as:

```
04-18 04:40:22.197: D/com.game.demo.Level1(15800): Broken Value! Debug! Debug!
```

when executing the following:

```
 if ("striiing" != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Broken Value! Debug! Debug!");
 prefs.getBoolean("name", true);
 prefs.getBoolean("player", true);
 prefs.getBoolean("points", true);
 prefs.getBoolean("level", true);
 prefs.getBoolean("gear", true);
```

Can anyone explain why a non existent value could/would show up as being NOT null? It's quite bizarre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"striiing"` is a String literal, which is a non null object in Java. Try this instead:

```
String s = null;
if (s == null) ...
```

And it should work as expected.